# Lightning internal error when Insert Email Template

Tags: lightning, email, lightning-experience, email-template

I try to insert email template in email in lightning experience but get internal error when modal window "Insert Email Template" opens. On classic everything works fine. It seems something related to permissions  because some other users can insert email templates without any errors but I have no idea what I need to add. (Error Id: 1684250086-84181 (-412177269))  [image]

[image]

Comment: (a) you'll want to contact support, and (b) it would be useful if you'd **[edit]** in the error number in as plain text so we can look in to it.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for answer. (b) - done. Error Id: 1684250086-84181 (-412177269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very strange thing but after I gave "read" access on Lead object(which we don't use at all in our project) issue have disappeared.